# varchar to decimal - error with convert()

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I have over 17,000 Excel sheets I need to open up and extract info from and store in a sql database. This all works fine as long as the sql data types are `varchar`.

I want to convert this `varchar` to `decimal`, so the data is easier to work with once it's moved to the next stage of the process. This is the error I get:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

This is the value in my sql statement. The code script is in PowerShell. Perhaps it is a simple syntax error. It does work without the convert bit.

```
convert(decimal(9,2),'"+$WorkSheet.Range('H49').Text.replace("'","''").replace(" ","").replace("$","")+"' )
```

Comment: First question to ask is the data valid for the conversion?  Also another option is to import it into SQL as the varchar, and have a step inside SQL that formats the data then

Comment: I'm not sure what's your doing with all the `replace` statements, but one of them is adding `''` (single quotes) to the string, that you are then trying to convert to a number...  **Quotations marks** are not numbers (therefore it can't convert to Decimal).  Regardless, whenever troubleshooting a multi-part formula, the first step is to **break it down into smaller pieces**, get each of them producing what you want them to, before combining into a longer, more complicated, formula.

Comment: Brad, now that you mention it that might be the issue. The data starts out as something that look like "$          10,210.23". I am stripping out apostrophes, blank spaces, and the $ but I'm not stripping out the comma which might be the problem.


Ashleedawg, if the users were to stick an apostrophe in there rather than a number I have it there to catch that. What you've recommended is how I ended up with the beast of a script I have now :). It's been a lot of fun. Like I mentioned above I think the comma might be an issue I'll try filtering that out and see if that makes it happy.

Answer (score 0):

My data looked like "$           10,210.23" which I was filtering down to look like "10,210.23". It failed to convert because of the comma which looking back is obviously not a number. After filtering it out in addition to the spaces and $ sign it worked like I expected it to. Thanks everyone.